# Can't build with ant when invoked from maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, build

I have an ant build file that works when invoked by itself.  When I invoke it from maven, the first few tasks execute fine (init, clean, etc.), but build fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (compile) on project maven-stream: An Ant BuildException has occur
ed: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] C:\maven_projects\cm\Qlarius Underwriter\build.xml:24: Unable to find a javac compiler;
[ERROR] com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
[ERROR] Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
[ERROR] It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre"
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="C:\maven_projects\cm/Qlarius Underwriter/build.xml">... @ 4:69 in C:\maven_projects\cm\target\antrun\build-ma
in.xml
```

Why would ant find java when invoked directly but not through maven?

The ant portion of the pom.xml file is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <ant antfile="${basedir}/Qlarius Underwriter/build.xml">
              <target name="LifeQuote"/>
            </ant>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests you're not pointing to a JDK.  You need to change JAVA_HOME to be the root of your JDK and not the JRE.  That way it will be able to find `javac`.

The other tasks `init` and `clean` will probably be ok if they are not using `javac`

Comment: I am pointing to a JDK.  If not, the build would not work when invoked from ant directly.  I can't determine why the jdk can't be found when invoked from maven instead of ant

Comment: C:\maven_projects\cm>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07

Comment: You need this `-Djava.home=${JAVA_HOME}` with mvn

Comment: I added the following to the ant area in the pom.xml file, seems to have solved that problem:
 <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                  <version>1.7.0</version>
                  <scope>system</scope>
                  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>